# Precedence of @@ vs /@

Tags: operators, precedence

How do I find what I think is called the "precedence" of a given operator. That is, for the following code:

```
CurveLength[c_Curve] := Plus @@ First /@ Cases[c, _Move]
```

What is the order of operations (ie. where would I apply parentheses)?

Comment: `{#, Precedence@#} & /@{Plus, Apply, Map}` => {{Plus, 310.}, {Apply, 620.}, {Map, 620.}}. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/819/106).  `Precedence` is undocumented as far as I know

Comment: See [`Operator Precedence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) table

Comment: Type `a @@ b /@ c`. Then select something, say `a`, and type control-period: the whole is selected showing the expression is parse `a @@ (b /@ c)`.  Now try it another way: say, select `c`.  Or yet another way: select one of the operator.  Control-period will extend the selection to the smallest syntactic unit containing the selection as a proper subexpression.  (This is how I check when I'm uncertain.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions concerning the operation of Wolfram|Alpha are explicitly excluded from being considered on this site.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Wolfram alpha what